# Is it good practice to pre-populate a web app with sample data?

Tags: first-impression

I am in the process of developing a web application which has various sections (tasks, documents, discussions etc.).

Currently the "blank-slate" state of the app is quite underwhelming, so I was thinking of adding some sample data for new users. This would hopefully give the users an idea of the potential future look and functionality of the app and make a better first impression.

My questions are :

1. Is this a commonly used approach?
2. Would users be irritated by having to delete the data?

Comment: I ended up doing something which I've never seen before but seems to be looking quite well so far. I am using Guiders.js (https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS) to show users a tour of the app, and for each step of the tour I inject html using the callbacks so as to show sample data but only for that step in the tour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this being used, and I think it's a good strategy to display to the user how the application is supposed to be used, **As long as you make it totally clear that it is fictive data.**
You want the user to get a quick look at what the application will do, but don't make the entries credible to a point where they're hard to distinguish from the real entries the user will add themselves.

I know that Eg. [Wunderlist](http://www.wunderlist.com/) uses this strategy. They populate the list with tutorial data, that shows how the list items are displayed/used and where each item tells the user how the app is used and some nifty shortcuts that they also can use.

Answer (score 5):

I'd agree with AndroidHustle. Using the blank slate as a tutorial seems like a really good idea.

Basecamp is an example that does this really well. It isn't just demo data, but a way to help the user create their own. There's a blog on their work (with examples) [here](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3210-backstage-designing-the-new-basecamp-blank-slates).

Answer (score 3):

[Sugar CRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/) is a good example of this. On installation it asks if you want demo data or a clean slate. Demo date is fictitious and just shows how elements and patterns use the data.

I would recommend **giving users the choice** and a quick and obvious way to remove the demo data.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a common approach and it can be useful for helping users to get a brief "tutorial" of how the application works.

You do correctly see the downside, which is removing the data.  I would echo Captain's recommendation of giving the user the option to seed the app with demo data on install/instatiation.

I would add that in the event that a user does elect to seed the app, that you include some UI element(s) that allows for one-click removal.